# Am I getting hacked?

Tags: error-handling, discord.py, bots

I am coding a discord bot in python in repl.it and a html error code showed up on the console which I copied and the website says this

Please enable cookies.

Error 1015

Ray ID: 6c3a567e8ad32c9b • 2021-12-28 12:33:29 UTC

You are being rate limited

What happened?

The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.

Cloudflare Ray ID: 6c3a567e8ad32c9b • Your IP: 34.82.151.245 • Performance & security by Cloudflare

I copied the IP into the google search and it said ヾ(*ФωФ)βyё βyё☆彡

Can Anyone tell me how to fix it?

Edit: Apparently I turned off/on my VPN and the repl.it result is the same (i.e. same IP error), although I google searched my ip address and the results are different

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rate limiting happens when websites block your application because they think that you're abusing web property, and these blocks help with stopping certain bot attacks. That's what [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/bots/what-is-rate-limiting/) is meant to do.

And as for you Googling your IP, it appears to be a website that's been port forwarded under the IP address that you posted. I wouldn't be too concerned about Discord rate limiting you, but I'm not so sure about the IP thing. If you're using a VPN (which you mentioned), you should be fine.

Then again, don't quote me on this because I'm not an expert on networking and how it works.